# How to correctly react to a failure action with redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, expo, redux-toolkit

I am using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) in my [Expo](https://expo.io/) ([React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)) app. I am using [createAsyncThunk](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#fetching-data-with-createasyncthunk) to create a *register* action. This creates the `pending`, `fulfilled` and `rejected` actions. Now the workflow is like this:

In my *RegisterScreen* I dispatch the `auth/register` action (created by `createAsyncThunk`). The [payloadCreator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) is executed. Let's assume that the server (My backend API) responds with a `'USERNAME_IS_TAKEN'` error, because the username that the user has chosen for his account is already taken. In the `payloadCreator` I call `return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue('USERNAME_IS_TAKEN');` and the reducer that handles the `auth/register/rejected` action stores the error in the state of the [authSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice).
Now I want to react to the error in the `RegisterScreen` and provide the username TextInput with a descriptive error message (How I react to the error is irrelevant to my question). But I don't know how to react to a state update of the error in the auth state in my `RegisterScreen` (which is a [class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components) connected to the redux store with [connect](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)).
How should I react to the update of the auth error in the `RegisterScreen`?

Comment: It sounds like you know what you are doing so I don’t quite get what the question is.  Use connect to select the error from authState and display some error component if the error you selected is truths.

Comment: I don't know how to handle the CHANGE of the error.

Comment: The connect HOC (and the useSelector) hook subscribe to the store so your props automatically update with the current value of error.